# If i wanted to send the cell only the [expanded_url] inside [urls] in Twitter API V2, how to define?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, twitter

I am trying to collect only a specific part of the result obtained from the Twitter V2 API, the details regarding the return and the script I am trying to use will be placed below:

The result data is:

```
[{"created_at":"2021-06-09T00:31:36.000Z","source":"Twitter Web App","public_metrics":{"retweet_count":0,"reply_count":0,"like_count":2,"quote_count":0},"conversation_id":"1402423096229826562","possibly_sensitive":false,"id":"1402423096229826562","entities":{"urls":[{"start":126,"end":149,"url":"https ://t.co /7PnohIUXzY","expanded_url":"https://stake.com/?iid=sport%3A10916236&modal=bet&c=view","display_url":"stake.com/?iid=sport%3A1…"},{"start":150,"end":173,"url":"https ://t.co /hrBwrm600W","expanded_url":"https://twitter.com/stakehighroller/status/1402423096229826562/photo/1","display_url":"pic.twitter.com/hrBwrm600W"}]},"lang":"en","author_id":"1310800524619386880","reply_settings":"everyone","attachments":{"media_keys":["3_1402423081155526658"]},"text":"ALERT: New high roller bet posted!\nA parlay bet has been placed for $20,000.00 to win $60,480.00.\nTo view this bet or copy it https: //t.co /7PnohIUXzY https ://t .co/hrBwrm600W"}
```

```
  {
    "created_at": "2021-06-09T00:31:36.000Z",
    "source": "Twitter Web App",
    "public_metrics": {
      "retweet_count": 0,
      "reply_count": 0,
      "like_count": 2,
      "quote_count": 0
    },
    "conversation_id": "1402423096229826562",
    "possibly_sensitive": false,
    "id": "1402423096229826562",
    "entities": {
      "urls": [
        {
          "start": 126,
          "end": 149,
          "url": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
          "expanded_url": "https://stake.com/?iid=sport%3A10916236&modal=bet&c=view",
          "display_url": "stake.com/?iid=sport%3A1…"
        },
        {
          "start": 150,
          "end": 173,
          "url": "YYYYYYYYYYYYYY",
          "expanded_url": "https://twitter.com/stakehighroller/status/1402423096229826562/photo/1",
          "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/hrBwrm600W"
        }
      ]
    },
    "lang": "en",
    "author_id": "1310800524619386880",
    "reply_settings": "everyone",
    "attachments": {
      "media_keys": [
        "3_1402423081155526658"
      ]
    },
    "text": "ALERT: New high roller bet posted!\nA parlay bet has been placed for $20,000.00 to win $60,480.00.\nTo view this bet or copy it XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
  }
```

My fail attempt:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tweets").getRange("A3");
  var obj_data = JSON.parse(responseApi.getContentText());
  ss.setValue(JSON.stringify(obj_data.data.entities.urls.expanded_url));
```

Expected value result:

```
https://stake.com/?iid=sport%3A10916236&modal=bet&c=view
```

Comment: My Google App Script response: ```TypeError: Cannot read property "urls" from undefined.```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the relationship between `The result data is:` and your sample value in the middle of question. I apologize for this. Can you provide the sample value of `responseApi.getContentText()`?

Comment: Ok, one minute please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `obj_data` is the top of data in your question, `console.log(obj_data.entities.urls[0].expanded_url)` is the result you expect?

So, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
ss.setValue(JSON.stringify(obj_data.data.entities.urls.expanded_url));
```

#### To:

```
ss.setValue(obj_data.entities.urls[0].expanded_url);
```

#### Testing:

```js
var obj_data = {
  "created_at": "2021-06-09T00:31:36.000Z",
  "source": "Twitter Web App",
  "public_metrics": {
    "retweet_count": 0,
    "reply_count": 0,
    "like_count": 2,
    "quote_count": 0
  },
  "conversation_id": "1402423096229826562",
  "possibly_sensitive": false,
  "id": "1402423096229826562",
  "entities": {
    "urls": [
      {
        "start": 126,
        "end": 149,
        "url": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "expanded_url": "https://stake.com/?iid=sport%3A10916236&modal=bet&c=view",
        "display_url": "stake.com/?iid=sport%3A1…"
      },
      {
        "start": 150,
        "end": 173,
        "url": "YYYYYYYYYYYYYY",
        "expanded_url": "https://twitter.com/stakehighroller/status/1402423096229826562/photo/1",
        "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/hrBwrm600W"
      }
    ]
  },
  "lang": "en",
  "author_id": "1310800524619386880",
  "reply_settings": "everyone",
  "attachments": {
    "media_keys": [
      "3_1402423081155526658"
    ]
  },
  "text": "ALERT: New high roller bet posted!\nA parlay bet has been placed for $20,000.00 to win $60,480.00.\nTo view this bet or copy it XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
};
console.log(obj_data.entities.urls[0].expanded_url);
```

Comment: I added at the beginning of the message the value of ```obj_data``` when it comes complete for the cell, unfortunately in the indicated model it keeps the error warning. Is it possible that some formatting is different?

Comment: @Brondby IF If the value of `obj_data` is `[{,,,}]`, when you test `ss.setValue(obj_data[0].entities.urls[0].expanded_url);`, what result will you obtain?

Comment: The indication was correct, the error was mine when copying, it was an extra text value that could not have been copied together. Thank you so much again!

Comment: @Brondby IF Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.